# Class Cast Exception Building WAR file in Grails 3.1.11 Using asset-pipeline and bootstrap

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I'm building a grails application using bootstrap and asset-pipeline. Everything works great in dev but when I build a war file I get a ClassCastException

> { viops } » gradle war
>   /c/VitalDev/ProfessionalServices/dev/trunk/viops :assetCompile
>   Processing File 1 of 164 - bower.json
>
> Writing File Processing File 2 of 164 - data/flot-data.js Minifying
>   File Writing File Processing File 3 of 164 - data/morris-data.js
>   Minifying File Writing File Processing File 4 of 164 -
>   dist/css/sb-admin-2.css Minifying File Writing File Processing File 5
>   of 164 - dist/css/sb-admin-2.min.css Writing File Processing File 6 of
>   164 - dist/js/sb-admin-2.js Minifying File Writing File Processing
>   File 7 of 164 - dist/js/sb-admin-2.min.js Writing File Processing File
>   8 of 164 - gulpfile.js :assetCompile FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with
>   an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':assetCompile'.
>
> Cannot cast object '[Digest Input Stream] MD5 Message Digest from SUN,
>   ' with class 'java.security.DigestInputStream' to class
>   'java.io.ByteArrayInputStream' Try: Run with --stacktrace option to
>   get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log
>   output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

Here's the stacktrace:

> Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution
>   failed for task ':assetCompile'. at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   at org.gra
>   dle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22) at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33) at
>   org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45) at
>   org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23) Caused by:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
>   cast object '[Digest Input Stream] MD5 Message Digest from SUN, ' with
>   class 'java.security.DigestInputStream' to class
>   'java.io.ByteArrayInputStream' at
>   asset.pipeline.AbstractAssetFile.processedStream(AbstractAssetFile.groovy:152)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.processors.JsRequireProcessor.encapsulateModule(JsRequireProcessor.groovy:115)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.processors.JsRequireProcessor.appendModule(JsRequireProcessor.groovy:103)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.processors.JsRequireProcessor.this$4$appendModule(JsRequireProcessor.groovy)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.processors.JsRequireProcessor$_process_closure1.doCall(JsRequireProcessor.groovy:62)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.processors.JsRequireProcessor.process(JsRequireProcessor.groovy:37)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.AbstractAssetFile.processedStream(AbstractAssetFile.groovy:171)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.AbstractAssetFile.processedStream(AbstractAssetFile.groovy)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor.fileContents(DirectiveProcessor.groovy:307)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor$fileContents$0.callCurrent(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor.loadContentsForTree(DirectiveProcessor.groovy:129)
>   at
>   asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor.compile(DirectiveProcessor.groovy:67)
>   at asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor$compile.call(Unknown Source) at
>   asset.pipeline.AssetCompiler.compile(AssetCompiler.groovy:147) at
>   asset.pipeline.AssetCompiler$compile.call(Unknown Source) at
>   asset.pipeline.gradle.AssetCompile.compile(AssetCompile.groovy:221) at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75) at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>   ... 57 more Total time: 22.617 secs

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion


    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
//        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.10.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.10"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.0.12"

        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.11.2'
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.11.2'
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-core:2.11.2' //Add this for some bug fixes
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.2"
    }
}
configurations.all {

    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.name == 'log4j') {
            details.useTarget "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.5"
        }
        if (details.requested.name == 'commons-logging') {
            details.useTarget "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5"
        }

    }
}

version "0.1"
group "viops"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

ext {

    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    //This top section pulls out Grails Logback logging solution and
    //replaces it with log4j2
    // added the new way using Log4j2, yes, spring makes it easy
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"

    // changed spring-boot-autoconfigure so that it would not
    // pull in the logback binding/implementation
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure') {
        exclude group:'ch.qos.logback', module:'logback-classic'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator') {
        exclude group:'ch.qos.logback', module:'logback-classic'
    }

    // and finally, added the log4j2 binding/implementation
    compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.5"
    compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5"

    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies" //
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"  //
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.11.2"
//    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:3.0.1"

    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.2"
    runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-core:2.11.2' //Add this for some bug fixes
    runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.11.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.4'

    //profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}
assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    excludes = ['**/*.less','bootstrap-3.3.2/**/*'] //Example Exclude GLOB pattern
    includes = ['application.less','bootstrap-3.3.2/fonts/*']
}
```

I don't know if I'm missing something or if it's a bug. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update: I'm now using 3.1.12 successfully.

I started playing with versions and combinations and wound up with only

```
classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.9.5
```

`and now it seems to work. After restricting to just this item in the classpath, I walked the version back one by one until I arrived at 2.9.5.

I still am not sure exactly which item this created a problem with or which version of which other package I'm using.